# How to undo changes in a model in Django-oscar

Tags: django, django-oscar

I tried adding a field in AbstractProduct model and in doing so, I was successful, but now that field is being presented whenever I go to product detail view as an empty field and which is not desirable.

[image: i changed the models in myapps/catalogue/models.py]

[image: I changed the productform in myapps/dashboard/catalogue/forms.py]

and in the following image the state of the origin is the issue which I am facing..which can't be left blank so no one can place order..

How to solve this ??

[image: problem]

Comment: Changes to the product model have no effect at all on the add-to-basket form - there is something else going on which is not visible in the information you have shared. It looks like you've eitheradded an "option" on the product/product class, which is what is causing an addition field to appear on the form, or you have modified the add-to-basket form in another way. Hard to be sure without seeing all your code.

Comment: Yes @solarissmoke, you are right, I do actually added that field as an option and later figured out the logic and flaw with my code…thank you for taking out time to answer this naive question…